# Greedy algorithm odd behavior

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I've implemented the Greedy algorithm to solve Egyptian fractions, however I'm getting some unexpected results. Here's my code

```
from math import ceil
from fractions import Fraction

def go(frac):
    ret = []
    while frac > 0:
        if frac.numerator == 1:
            ret.append(frac)
            break
        x = Fraction(1, ceil(frac.denominator / frac.numerator))
        frac -= x
        ret.append(x)
    return ret

input1 = int(raw_input('numerator: '))
input2 = int(raw_input('denominator: '))

print go(Fraction(input1, input2))
```

I constantly am getting the error **"TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances"**

I've been logging and it crashes upon the first iteration of the while loop.

EDIT: the error in detail is:

```
File "egypt.py", line 19, in <module>
print go(Fraction(input1, input2))
File "egypt.py", line 10, in go
x = Fraction(1,ceil(frac.denominator / frac.numerator))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/fractions.py", line 158, in __new__
raise TypeError("both arguments should be "
TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances
```

Why is this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
x = Fraction(1, ceil(frac.denominator / frac.numerator))
```

to this:

```
x = Fraction(1,int(ceil(frac.denominator / float(frac.numerator))))
```

Comment: First, `frac.denominator` and `frac.numerator` are ints, so the division is integer division, which rounds down and can result in 0 values, so you need to cast to a float to get the division right.
Second, `ceil` returns a float, so you need to convert to an int because `Fraction` requires two ints.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems in your code.

1. you're dividing `int` with `int` which always returns an `int`; in your case, you're dividing `a / b` where `a < b` so it'll always be rounded down to 0.
2. Then, you `ceil()` that, which returns a `float` (0.0) which is something `Fraction` doesn't like;it wants `int`s.

So try this instead:

```
Fraction(1, int(ceil(float(frac.denominator) / frac.numerator)))
```

The rest of the code looks good.